# Does CocoaLibSpotify work on 5s?

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

For some reason I can get the test application (LSTests) to work, but cannot seem to get my app which uses cocoalibspotify to work (despite the fact that my app works on all previous iphones i've tried). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"Work" is an incredibly vague word to use. Does it crash on launch? What error? Does it compile? If not, what error?

Be aware, though, that CocoaLibSpotify doesn't support the arm64 architecture, so you'll have to switch that off in your app to get it to compile.